# Unity Compute Shader runs significantly slower than CPU implementation. Is there somewhere I can optimise?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compute-shader

I'm new to using Unity compute shaders but have implemented a fluid solver in a script and a compute shader but the script is significantly faster even at high numbers of points to be simulated.
Is there anything majorly wrong with how I've implemented the shader? I think it might be the data I'm sending causing a bottleneck but I'm not entirely sure. Here is the function that runs the shader:

```
public struct dataLaxF
{
    //Input Data
    public Vector4 heightData;
    public Vector4 fUData;
    public Vector4 fVData;
    public Vector4 uData;
    public Vector4 vData;

    //Output Data
    public float outputHeight;
    public float outputFU;
    public float outputFV;
    public float outputU;
    public float outputV;
};

 //Runs the algorithm on the GPU
    public void SimulateGPU()
    {
        //Profiler Testing Start 
        Profiler.BeginSample("GPULaxF");

        //Set data to structs for GPU
        for (int x = 1; x < xGridSize-1; x++)
            for (int y = 1; y < yGridSize-1; y++)
            {
              
                dataLaxF inData = new dataLaxF();
                inData.heightData = new Vector4(height[x + 1, y], height[x - 1, y], height[x, y + 1], height[x, y - 1]);
                inData.fUData = new Vector4(fU[x + 1, y], fU[x - 1, y], fU[x, y + 1], fU[x, y - 1]);
                inData.fVData = new Vector4(fV[x + 1, y], fV[x - 1, y], fV[x, y + 1], fV[x, y - 1]);
                inData.uData = new Vector4(u[x + 1, y], u[x - 1, y], u[x, y + 1], u[x, y - 1]);
                inData.vData = new Vector4(v[x + 1, y], v[x - 1, y], v[x, y + 1], v[x, y - 1]);

                inData.outputHeight = height[x, y];
                inData.outputFU = fU[x, y];
                inData.outputFV = fV[x, y];
                inData.outputU = u[x, y];
                inData.outputV = v[x, y];


                data[(x * xGridSize) + y] = inData;
            }

        //Send data to GPU
        int totalSize = sizeof(float) * 25;
        ComputeBuffer dataBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(data.Length, totalSize);

        dataBuffer.SetData(data);
        computeShader.SetBuffer(0, "vDatas", dataBuffer);
        computeShader.Dispatch(0, data.Length / 128, 1, 1);

        dataBuffer.GetData(data);

        //Recieve and read data
        for (int x = 1; x < xGridSize-1; x++)
            for (int y = 1; y < xGridSize-1; y++)
            {
                dataLaxF outData = data[x * xGridSize + y];
                height[x, y] = outData.outputHeight;
                fU[x, y] = outData.outputFU;
                fV[x, y] = outData.outputFV;
                u[x, y] = outData.outputU;
                v[x, y] = outData.outputV;
            }

        dataBuffer.Dispose();
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
```

And this is the compute shader:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

struct dataLaxF
{
    //Input Data
    float4 heightData;
    float4 fUData;
    float4 fVData;
    float4 uData;
    float4 vData;

    //Output Data
     float outputHeight;
     float outputFU;
     float outputFV;
     float outputU;
     float outputV;
};


//Data struct arrays
RWStructuredBuffer<dataLaxF> vDatas;

//Kernel for Lax Friedrichs
[numthreads(128,1,1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float alpha = 0.02f;
    float g = 9.8f;
    dataLaxF data = vDatas[id.x]; 

    //Height
    data.outputHeight = 0.25f * (data.heightData.x + data.heightData.y + data.heightData.z + data.heightData.a) - alpha * (data.fUData.x - data.fUData.y) - alpha * (data.fVData.z - data.fVData.a);

    //FU
    data.outputFU = 0.25f * (data.fUData.x + data.fUData.y + data.fUData.z + data.fUData.a);
    data.outputFU = data.outputFU - alpha * ((data.heightData.x * (data.uData.x* data.uData.x) + (0.5f * g * (data.heightData.x* data.heightData.x))) - (data.heightData.y * (data.uData.y* data.uData.y) + (0.5f * g * (data.heightData.y* data.heightData.y))));
    data.outputFU = data.outputFU - alpha * (data.heightData.z * data.vData.z * data.uData.z - data.heightData.a * data.vData.a * data.uData.a);

    //FV
    data.outputFV = 0.25f * (data.fVData.x + data.fVData.y + data.fVData.z + data.fVData.a);
    data.outputFV = data.outputFV - alpha * (data.heightData.x * data.vData.x * data.uData.x - data.heightData.y * data.vData.y * data.uData.y);
    data.outputFV = data.outputFV - alpha * ((data.heightData.z * (data.vData.z* data.vData.z) + (0.5f * g *(data.heightData.z* data.heightData.z))) - (data.heightData.a * (data.vData.a* data.vData.a) + (0.5f * g * (data.heightData.a* data.heightData.a))));

    //U
    data.outputU = data.outputFU / data.outputHeight;

    //V
    data.outputV = data.outputFV / data.outputHeight;

    vDatas[id.x] = data;
    
    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should measure the timing of Dispatch and the rest (in particular, the `new ComputBuffer, getData & setData`) to know. Your shader seems ok at first glance, since this is a very simple computation that runs on each element independently with no scattered memory access.